# Elemento con propiedad flex ¿ Como desactivar el resize width del elemento?

Tags: html5, css3

Tengo un contenedor  con la propiedad display: flex 
Dentro del contenedor tengo varios elementos alineados horizontalmente entre si.
Cuando cambio el tamaño de la ventana algunos de los elementos su ancho va cambiando por ejemplo en los elementos

¿ Cómo puedo hacer que no me cambien el ancho de ciertos elementos ? 
En mi caso me interesaría que no cambiara el tamaño de "boton2"

Ejemplo:

HTML:

```
<div class ="contenedor">
  <div class ="celda" >
    <span class="titulo1">Titulo1</span>
    <span class="titulo2">Titulo2</span>
    <button class="boton1">Boton1</button>
    <button class="boton2" />
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.celda {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
```

}

```
.boton2 {
   width: 30px;
   height: 30px;
   border: 1px solid;
   background: url("../imagen/imagen.png");
}
```

Comment: Si nos pegas el trozo de HTML y los CSS que afectan al elemento con display flex que nos mencionas, podríamos ayudarte mejor.

Comment: Ok, acabo de poner el trozo de codigo

Comment: En las pruebas que estoy haciendo con el código que has subido, no me da problemas de que se redimensione, sería extraño que sucediera teniendo el tamaño del elemento a pixeles fijos. ¿Es posible que tengas alguna otra regla CSS que esté afectando al width del elemento y que tenga más prioridad?

Comment: He añadido la imagen del botón que tenia puesta que no puse para simplificar. Puede que según que navegador se use alomejor no se note. En mi caso el ancho del botón2 me lo cambia con lo que se ve el botón mas pequeño

Comment: La única explicación que le encuentro es que exista otra regla CSS que esté pisando al width que tienes establecido en .boton2 y que le esté dando una medida relativa de tamaño (como por porcentaje). Yo inspeccionaría el elemento y revisaría las reglas que le están afectando. También puedes darle un width: 30px !important para tratar de conseguir que sea este width el que prime por encima de los de las otras posibles reglas que le afecten.

Comment: Lo he revisado y esta todo bien. No existen mas reglas css

Comment: ¿Qué navegador estás usando para hacer las pruebas? A ver si usando el mismo que tú consigo ver que te puede estar ocurriendo. ¿Estás haciendo las pruebas solamente con el código que has pegado aquí o tienes más código? Prueba si no ha dejar solamente el código que estés testeando para asegurarnos por completo que no esté afectando nada más.

Comment: Uso el navegador Firefox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tras hacer diferentes tipo de pruebas a través de los datos que me has ido dando, he comprobado que efectivamente, en Firefox, aunque pongas un item con width a píxeles fijos, te lo reescala.

Tras seguir realizando algunas pruebas he dado con el tema que te permitiría usar el flex box sin que se te produzca este "inconveniente".

Puedes usar la propiedad **min-width** en los elementos que no desees que te reescalen, pudiendo controlar de esta manera tú mismo su comportamiento.

**CSS**

```
.boton2 {
    width: 500px;
    min-width: 500px;
}
```

Comment: Gracias ! Funciona perfecto